# How To Remove iMessage Icon On Toolbar (MacBook Pro)

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, messages, desktop, menu-bar

How would i remove this icon in my toolbar on my MacBook Pro?
I have never really used it and would like to remove it from the toolbar.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The ol' Cmd-drag can (re)move the built-in icons up there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this by opening iMessage or Messages on your MBP. Then going to Messages->Preferences

There is an option in here to remove it from your menu bar [image: status in menu bar]

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Although this is Mac help site, where we are glad to answer questions, reading thru [Apple's Mac Basics](http://www.apple.com/support/macbasics/) would aquaint you with the Preferences settings every application has.